# How to access second level JSON object via $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi guys please take a look at this having trouble reaching second level inside a object that looks like this:

```
{
    "results": [{
        "title": "TEAM",
        "subtitle": "athletes",
        "offset": 0,
        "icon": "info",
        "relevance": 1,
        "link": {
            "title": "HOME",
            "url": "http://www.test.com",
            "id": "23458"
        }]
}
```

and this is the code I have:

```
var theJson = {
    init: function() {
        this.url = 'http://test.com/js?jsonfeed=123123';
        this.fetch();
    },

    fetch: function() {
        $.getJSON(this.url, function( data ){
            var obj = $.map(data.results, function( newObj ){
                return {
                    title: newObj .title,
                    icon: newObj.icon,
                    topic: newObj.link.id, //??
                    topic: newObj["link"].id //??
                    topic: newObj[1].id //??
                };
            });
        });

    }
};

theJson.init();
```

My question is how do I reach the id var in link array inside results object? Thank guys you all rock!

Comment: The JSON you posted is invalid, it's missing a `}`. Typo or actual problem? `newObj.link.id` will work (as will the second possibility), have you tried it?

Comment: sorry yes that's just a typo... I did try newObj.link.id... keep getting this Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: Then have a look what `newObj` actually is: `console.log(newObj)`.

Comment: I did, newObj is where i'm storing my new setting so it comes back undefined, but when I console.log('obj') which is the main var I get my new object but still no access to link.id :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it correct the first and second time:

```
newObj.link.id
newObj["link"].id
```

There are both correct ways to get the id under link.

Comment: Thanks that's what I thought but still I get an error:( BUT i'm able to get to the object newObj['link'], but when I enter the id newObj['link'].id comes back as an error..any ideas please share!?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily access it by index, like that:

`newObj["link"][0]`